Computing direct product of irreps in a point group
I want to calculate the direct product of two or more irreps in the character table of any point group. Let's say I take the $D_3$ group and compute the product of $E \otimes E = A_1+ A_2+E.$ How can I derive this result using GAP? Moreover, the product can also be decomposed into antisymmetric and symmetric components. Can this be also done?

Yes. Look at the manual chapter about class functions, in particular the operations TensorProduct and ScalarProduct (or MatScalarProducts).
